# Scala: Minimal "Type Class" for operator overloading on some UDT?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, user-defined-functions, typeclass

I'm trying to learn the scala "Type Class" capability and this is my failed attempt at it. In this example I'm trying to create pluggable operators on an UDT:

```
package playground 

// my UDT
class Element(val value : Integer)

trait AdditiveOps {
    def +(e2: Element): Element
    def -(e2: Element): Element
}

// One possible implementation of AdditiveOps
class AdditiveOpsImpl(val e1: Element) extends AdditiveOps {
    def +(e2: Element): Element = {
      new Element(e1.value + e2.value)
    }

    def -(e2: Element): Element = {
      new Element(e1.value - e2.value)
    }
}

// What needs to be imported
object ElementOps {
  implicit def +(e1: Element) : AdditiveOps = {
    new AdditiveOpsImpl(e1)
  }

  implicit def -(e1: Element) : AdditiveOps = {
    new AdditiveOpsImpl(e1) 
  }
}
```

then using it like this:

```
package playground 

object Main {
  import ElementOps._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val e1 = new Element(2)
    val e2 = new Element(3)
    val e3 = e1 + e2

    println("Hello Class Types %s".format(e3.value))
  }
}
```

but I get the following compiler error:

```
type mismatch;  found   : e1.type (with underlying type playground.Element)  required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: playground.Element): ?} Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:  both method + in object ElementOps of type (e1: playground.Element)playground.AdditiveOps  and method - in object ElementOps of type (e1: playground.Element)playground.AdditiveOps  are possible conversion functions from e1.type to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: playground.Element): ?}    Main.scala  /Playground/src/playground  line 9  Scala Problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh found the problem, it is in my `ElementOps` object implementation. I need instead:

```
object ElementOps {
   implicit def additive(e1: Element) : AdditiveOps = {
      new AdditiveOpsImpl(e1)
   }
}
```

basically implement the implicit method only once and name it in any way I like e.g. `additive` but it can be `whatever` and not using the operators. After fixing it, the output as expected is: `Hello class types 5`